# Making an XMLHttpRequest through a proxy?

Tags: javascript, http, browser, proxy

Is it possible to route HTTP requests through a proxy server programmatically from the browser with JavaScript?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean a standard HTTP proxy: No. The use of a proxy server is a browser configuration setting and cannot be changed (or even temporarily overridden) from JS.

You could make an HTTP request to a regular HTTP endpoint on a server that determines the response it should make by making an HTTP request to a different server.

Comment: Thanks. What about a browser extension; can something like chrome extension do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some browser-extensions like "Bettenet VPN Proxy" or "Bear VPN" for this (Chrome).