# Elm Http request through proxy

Tags: http, elm

I am trying to make an Http request which needs to go through a proxy. I saw an answer referring how to do it with create-elm-app, but I am not using this and was wondering if there is an easy method of doing this? I have tried with the Via header (left down below to see the use I am going for), but that probably has nothing to do with it.

Do I need to use some kind of behind the scene trickery or is there a native way of doing it?

```
 fetchUiElements : Cmd Msg
 fetchUiElements =
 let
     baseUrl = "https://example.com/"

     responseDecoder =
         Json.Decode.field "data" Json.Decode.string

     httpBody =
         Http.jsonBody <|
             Json.Encode.object
                 [ ("", Json.Encode.string "")
                 , ("", Json.Encode.string "")
                 ]


 in
     Http.request
        { method = "POST"
        , headers = [ Http.header "Via" "http://proxy.com:8888"]
        , url = baseUrl ++ "getUiElements"
        , body = httpBody
        , timeout = Nothing
        , tracker = Nothing
        , expect = Http.expectJson FetchUiElements responseDecoder
        }
```

Edit: For further clarification I want the same behaviour as this curl

`curl -x "http://proxy:8888" -v https://endpoint/getstuff`

Comment: The Via header is generally added by the proxy instead of by the client (Elm app). This page has a pretty simple description of it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Via. 

This depends on how you proxy is setup, but I think setting `baseUrl = "http://proxy.com:8888"` might be what your looking for. If not could you give more information on what type of proxy you are using.

Comment: I don't understand 100% how the proxy works. I know I need to call the endpoint through/from the proxy to be able to access it. I have added a working curl example.

Comment: to be able to access the endpoint*

Comment: I think you are hitting a browser - not an Elm - limitation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43895039/making-an-xmlhttprequest-through-a-proxy

Comment: Feared as much... Thanks a lot for the answer @SimonH